# MYSQL: ORDER BY table selected on the fly by user

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

Table: Cols

```
 col1   col2    col3    col4
------ ------  ------  -------
  1       2       5       8
  5       4       2       7
  5       3       7       4
  7       5       4       1
```

its very important what sort column be selected by user, i try something like:

```
    SELECT col1,Col2,Col3
    FROM Cols
    order by cast(:ORDER_ID_COL as integer)
```

or

```
    SELECT col1,Col2,Col3
    FROM Cols
    order by cast(:ORDER_ID_COL as varchar(20))
```

Both without errors but none correct.

If I'm out of the way, please enlighten me to get back on track.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but this kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `:ORDER_ID_COL` to sql, it will be taken as a value not a column, so it won't produce the order what you want, in other words your query like following:

```
SELECT col1,Col2,Col3
FROM Cols
order by 'col1'
```

You can use a ugly way to do that:

```
SELECT col1,Col2,Col3
FROM Cols
order by case when :ORDER_ID_COL = 'col1' then col1
              when :ORDER_ID_COL = 'col2' then col2
              when :ORDER_ID_COL = 'col3' then col3
              when :ORDER_ID_COL = 'col4' then col4
         end
```

Or use dynamic sql:

```
SET @sql = concat('select col1,Col2,Col3 from cols order by ', :ORDER_ID_COL);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY :::

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(10) = '/*Here, pass the column name(if multiple columns, pass column names separated by commas)*/'
DECLARE @SQLquery VARCHAR(MAX) = '    
SELECT col1,Col2,Col3
FROM Cols
order by ' + @OrderBy

EXEC (@SQLquery)
```

Comment: OP tagged `mysql` not `sql-server`.